# How to perform mTLS client certificate verification using @sap-cloud-sdk in node js

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have a node js app deployed in SAP BTP,need to expose webhook endpoints for SAP Event Broker (Integration suite) which requires the webhook endpoints to be mTLS enabled (i.e authentication using only client Certificates)

Is there a way to do mTLS client certificate verification using SAP cloud sdk? I am using SAP xsuaa with app router for authentication and authorization

I am using SAP xsuaa with app router for authentication

Answer (score 0):

the SAP Cloud SDK is all about service consumption and it does not provide any functionality for service provisioning.
So, with the SDK you can consume your mTLS enabled service conveniently, but you cannot enable mTLS in your service.

I found this [documentation from the approuter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/approuter#mutual-tls-authentication-mtls-and-certificates-handling) on MTLS, maybe that helps a bit.